# How to quickly insert an element into array with duplicates after all of the equal elements?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an ArrayList, which contains game objects sorted by their 'Z' (float) position from lower to higher. I'm not sure if ArrayList is the best choice for it but I have come up with such a solution to find an index of insertion in a complexity faster than linear (worst case):

```
        GameObject go = new GameObject();
        int index = 0;
        int start = 0, end = displayList.size(); // displayList is the ArrayList
        while(end - start > 0)
        {
            index = (start + end) / 2;
            if(go.depthZ >= displayList.get(index).depthZ)
                start = index + 1;
            else if(go.depthZ < displayList.get(index).depthZ)
                end = index - 1;
        }
        while(index > 0 && go.depthZ < displayList.get(index).depthZ)
            index--;
        while(index < displayList.size() && go.depthZ >= displayList.get(index).depthZ)
            index++;
```

The catch is that the element has to be inserted in a specific place in the chain of elements with equal value of depthZ - at the end of this chain. That's why I need 2 additional while loops after the binary search which I assume aren't too expensive becouse binary search gives me some approximation of this place.

Still I'm wondering if there's some better solution or some known algorithms for such problem which I haven't heard of? Maybe using different data structure than ArrayList? At the moment I ignore the worst case insertion O(n) (inserting at the begining or middle) becouse using a normal List I wouldn't be able to find an index to insert using method above.

Comment: Why don't you use a `HashMap` or something like that, and map to each value, the number of occurrences?

Comment: ah sorry, forgot to mention that depthZ values are floats so there's just too many of possible values

Comment: Insertion in the middle of the array is expensive thus bringing to nothing speed of binary search. You can use `TreeMap<Float, List<GameObject>>` for what you need.

Comment: btw, there are no more different values of `float`s than of `int`s since they both are 4-byte.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use balanced search tree (red-black tree for example) instead of array. First you can try to use `TreeMap` witch uses a red-black tree inside to see if it's satisfy your requirements. Possible implementation:

```
Map<Float, List<Object>> map = new TreeMap<Float, List<Object>>(){
    @Override
    public List<Object> get(Object key) {
        List<Object> list = super.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            put((Float) key, list);
        }
        return list;
    }
};
```

Example of usage:

```
map.get(0.5f).add("hello");
map.get(0.5f).add("world");
map.get(0.6f).add("!");
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 to the least significant byte of the key (with carry); binary search for that insert position; and insert it there.

Your binary search has to be so constructed as to end at the leftmost of a sequence of duplicates, but this is trivial given an understanding of the various Binary search algorithms.

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan There is a major difference between an answer you didn't understand and 'not an answer'. There is nothing here that critiques the question or seeks clarification, but there is, and always was, a specification of an algorithm. Your comment remains incomprehensible.

Comment: Irrelevant. It got there because you voted  'not an answer', and it's been up there in black and white with your name on it. Unless and until you delete it, it will be taken as an expression of your views by everybody. Including me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would to do a halving search, where the first search is half way thru your list (list.size()/2), then for the next one you can do half of that, and so on. With this exponential method, instead of having to do 4096 searches when you have 4096 objects, you only need 12 searches

sorry for the complete disregard for technical terms, I am not the best at terms :P

Comment: What your propose is called binary search and OP already does that: `index = (start + end) / 2;`

Comment: ah dang, i didnt see that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Unless I overlook something, your approach is essentially correct (but there's an error, see below), in the sense that your first while tries to compute the insert-index such that it will be placed after all lower OR EQUAL Z: there's correctly an equal sign in your first test (updating "start" if it yields TRUE).

Then, of course, there's no need to worry anymore about its position among equals. However, your follow-up while destroys this nice situation: the test in the first follow-up while yields always TRUE (one time) and so you move back; and then you need the second follow-up while to undo that. So, you should remove BOTH follow-up whiles and you're done...

However, there's a little problem with your first while, such that it doesn't always exactly do what the purpose is. I guess that the faulty outcomes triggered you to implement the follow-up whiles to "repair" that.

Here's the issue in your while. Suppose you have a try-index (start+end)/2 that points to a larger Z, but the one just before it has value Z. You then get into your second test (elseif) and set "end" to the position where that Z-value resides. Finally you wind up with precisely that position.
The remedy is simple: in your elseif assignment, put "end = index" (without the -1). Final remark: the test in the elseif is unnecessary, just else is sufficient.

So, all in all you get

```
GameObject go = new GameObject();
int index = 0;
int start = 0, end = displayList.size(); // displayList is the ArrayList
while(end - start > 0)
{
    index = (start + end) / 2;
    if(go.depthZ >= displayList.get(index).depthZ)
        start = index + 1;
    else
        end = index;
}
```

(I hope I haven't overlooked something trivial...)